# jQuery -how to Bind DropDownlist with Sql Database -Asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server-2008

.cs Code Here

```
[WebMethod]
    public DataTable GetName()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("CodeNo", typeof(string));
        dt.Rows.Add("Delhi","D01");
        dt.Rows.Add("Noida", "N01");
        return dt;
    }
```

code here

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $().ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Home.aspx/GetName",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        $("#City").get(0).options.length = 0;
                        $("#City").get(0).options[0] = new Option("--Select--", "-1");
                     ?.......Here   ....................?
                      });
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Failed to load ");
                    }
                });
            });
```

My Out Put

-**-Select--**   only , **but  i want...  DataTable Row ("Delhi","Noida") in  SelectList Or DropDpwnlist** 
like

```
   -Select--
    Delhi
    Noida
```

Comment: What does your udon call back look like?

Comment: How about returning the full code of the dropdownlist with the list already populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.cs Code

```
[WebMethod]
    public string  GetName()
    {
        string Result = string.Empty;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("CodeNo", typeof(string));
        dt.Rows.Add("Delhi", "D01");
        dt.Rows.Add("Noida", "N01");

        if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
        {

            foreach (DataRow Dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                Result = string.Concat(Result + "<option value=" + Dr["CodeNo"] + ">" + Dr["Name"] + "</option>");
            }
        }

        return Result;
    }
```

**Code for  .aspx**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $().ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Home.aspx/GetName",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        $("#City").html(msg.d)

                      });
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Failed to load ");
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your back-end code looks fine. I see you are using JSON to populate the dropdown. Have a look at the code below. I use it quite often.

```
$.getJSON("Home.aspx/GetName", function (data) {
    var dropDown = $("#City");
    dropDown.append($("<option></option>").val('').text('- Select -'));

    $.each(data, function () {
        dropDown.append($("<option></option>")
            .val($(this).attr("CodeNo"))
            .text($(this).attr("Name")));
    });

});
```